# Implementation of Heap Sort

Tags: java, sorting, heap

Is this the correct implementation of Heap Sort using Java? How can it be improved further?

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class HeapSort {

    public static int heapSize;
    public static int LEFT(int i)
    {
        //returns left index of a zero index based array
        return 2*i+1;
    }

    public static int RIGHT(int i)
    {
        //returns right index of a zero based array
        return 2*i+2;
    }


    public static void BUILD_MAX_HEAP(int A[])
    {
        heapSize = A.length;//heap size initialised
        for(int i=A.length/2; i>=0;i--)//since n/2, n/2+1 ... are leaves we can start from n/2 step downwards
        {
            //call MAX_HEAPIFY on each root node starting from n/2
            MAX_HEAPIFY(A, i);
        }
    }


    public static void MAX_HEAPIFY(int A[],int i)
    {
        int l=LEFT(i);//the left element's index which is 2*i+1 (for zero based indexed array)
        int r=RIGHT(i);//right index = 2*i+2;
        int largestElementIndex = -1;//index can't be negative so initialise largest index , it will be used later
        //heapSize is the current size of the heap being worked upon
        //check if left index lies within the heap.
        //if element at left index is greater than root(A[i]) element, max heap property is violated
        //copy the index of violated element in largestElementIndex
        if(l<heapSize && A[l]>A[i]){
            largestElementIndex = l;
        }
        else //if max heap property is not violated copy the root's index in largestElementIndex
        {
            largestElementIndex=i;
        }
        //check to see the right sub tree for max heap property violation
        //here the largestElementIndex is calculated from previous step
        if(r<heapSize && A[r]>A[largestElementIndex])
        {
            largestElementIndex = r;
        }
        //if root doesn't has the largest index then swap the largest element with root element

        if(largestElementIndex!=i)
        {
            int temp = A[i];
            A[i]=A[largestElementIndex];
            A[largestElementIndex]=temp;
            //after swap, recursively call the MAX_HEAPIFY on the largest index(root element)
            MAX_HEAPIFY(A, largestElementIndex);
        }
    }

    public static void HEAP_SORT(int A[])
    {
        //max heap is built with heapSize initialised
        BUILD_MAX_HEAP(A);
        //starting from end loop through entire array
        for(int i=A.length-1;i>=0;i--)
        {
            //since heap is already heapified and maintains max heap property
            //the first element of the array is root of max heap
            //swap it with the extreme element of the array i.e. setting the largest element to the end of array
            int temp = A[0];
            A[0]=A[i];
            A[i]=temp;
            //reduce the heap window by 1
            heapSize  = heapSize-1;
            //call max heapify on the reduced heap
            MAX_HEAPIFY(A,0);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        int A[] = new int[]{4,1,3,2,16,9,10,14,8,7};
        HEAP_SORT(A);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(A));
    }
}
```

Comment: Constant values are generally UPPERCASE. By convention, method names are camelCase and class names are PascalCase (aka TitleCase).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As everyone has immediately pointed out, please stick with the `namingConventions` for methods and parameter names.

Your code is not object oriented, as Java code should be.  One sign is that you are using `static` functions everywhere.  Another hint is that the name of a class should always be a noun; if it's a verb then your objects are likely to be crappy.  You want to define a `MaxHeap` class.  Its outline should look like this:

```
public class MaxHeap {
    private int data[];
    private int size;

    public static void sort(int data[]) { ... }

    public MaxHeap(int data[]) { ... }
    public int removeNext() { ... }
    public int size() { return this.size; }

    private int leftChild(int i) { return 2 * i + 1; }
    private int rightChild(int i) { return 2 * i + 2; }
    private void heapify(int i) { ... }
}
```

Decide what operations you want to publicly support in your interface.  You'll need the constructor.  Since you will be doing removal of the root node in your `HEAD_SORT()` function anyway, you might as well support that in the public interface as `removeNext()`.  A `size()` method is trivial to implement.  It would be nice to implement `add(int datum)` as well, but for now let's leave it out since it's not necessary for your immediate goal of implementing heapsort.  We should also provide `sort(int[] data)` as a class method, because that is the point of this exercise.  (There's no need to call it `heapSort(int[] data)`, as "heap" is already part of the name of the class.)  Everything else should be declared `private` — the inner workings of the class are nobody else's business.

The heap constructor is just your `BUILD_MAX_HEAP()` code.  The only real correction I would make is that you can start `i` one element before where you did.

```
public MaxHeap(int data[]) {
    this.data = data;
    this.size = data.length;
    for (int i = size / 2 - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        heapify(i);
    }
}
```

Now, on to the `heapify()` method.  There's no need to call it `maxHeapify()`, since it's a member of the `MaxHeap` class.  It can just take one parameter, since the data array is now an instance variable.  Also,

```
private void heapify(int i) {
    // You might as well start with this optimistic assumption
    int largestElementIndex = i;

    // The optimistic assumption leads to nice parallelism between the
    // left-child and right-child cases.
    int l = leftChild(i);
    if (l < size && data[l] > data[largestElementIndex]) {
        largestElementIndex = l;
    }
    int r = rightChild(i);
    if (r < size && data[r] > data[largestElementIndex]) {
        largestElementIndex = r;
    }

    // If heap consistency was locally violated
    if (largestElementIndex != i) {
        int swap = data[i];
        data[i] = data[largestElementIndex];
        data[largestElementIndex] = swap;

        // Recursively heapify the affected sub-tree
        heapify(largestElementIndex);
    }
}
```

Here's `removeNext()`.  It returns the next largest element (the root node value) and shrinks the heap.

```
public int removeNext() throws NoSuchElementException {
    if (size == 0) {
        throw new NoSuchElementException();
    }
    int next = data[0];
    data[0] = data[--size];
    heapify(0);
    return next;
}
```

Finally, here's `sort()`.

```
public static void sort(int[] data) {
    MaxHeap heap = new MaxHeap(data);
    for (int i = heap.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        int nextMax = heap.removeNext();

        // This is a rather naughty move, since heap.data is
        // aliased to data.  We do this only because we know
        // from the way the heap works that the end of the array
        // can be used to store our sorted result in place.
        data[i] = nextMax;
    }
}
```

---

One thing I'm not happy about in the above code is the fact that the `MaxHeap` adopts the input array rather than making a copy.  That is probably surprising behaviour to users of the class, who probably don't expect the contents of the passed-in `data` array to be modified.

On the other hand, it's nice to be able to implement `sort()` in place without allocating another array.

One cop-out would be to make the constructor private, essentially declaring that the code in this class is only usable through the `sort()` function.

A workaround is to implement two variants of the constructor, such that you have to explicitly ask for the array to be adopted:

```
/**
 * Copies the data
 */
public MaxHeap(int data[]) {
    this(data, true);
}

/**
 * If copyData is false, MaxHeap adopts the data array, and may overwrite its
 * contents; it does not make a copy!
 */
public MaxHeap(int data[], boolean copyData) {
    this.data = copyData ? Arrays.copyOf(data, data.length) : data;
    ...
}

public static void sort(int[] data) {
    MaxHeap heap = new MaxHeap(data, false);
    ...
}
```

Comment: I don't know why this was flagged as protected considering this is the only answer on here and no where near low-quality.  Great and thorough explanation.

Comment: @JustLikeThat There are a few deleted answers that you don't see.